# Check if JSON object is null or empty in PL/JSON

Tags: oracle11g, pljson

I have a script that has two loops, each doing some appending to a JSON object. Both loops append a json object to a json list. I finally have the formatting figured out, but it is also returning empty json objects. Is there a way in PL/JSON to check for empty JSON objects?

I have tried `if (my_json_obj is not null) then` to no avail.

Here is what my expected return result should look like:

```
{
  "Outer List": [{
    "Inner List": [{
      "Val1": "2015-03-13T13:30:13.5593965Z",
      "Val2": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "Val3": "BS2345"
    }, {
      "Val1": "2015-03-14T13:30:13.5593965Z",
      "Val2": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "Val3": "5678B"
    }],
    "Inner Object Value": "prk1"
  }, {
    "Inner List 2": [{
      "Val1": "2015-03-13T13:30:13.5593965Z",
      "Val2": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "Val3": "1234A"
    }],
    "Inner Object Value": "prk2"
  }]
}
```

EDIT: Here's what my code looks like

```
declare
outer_json_obj json := json();-- Main JSON object. Contains all permit zone list 
outer_json_list json_list := json_list(); -- List inside outer json obj. Contains list of permits per zone
inner_json_obj json := json(); -- Object inside permit zone list. Contains list of permits per zone id
inner_json_list json_list := json_list(); -- innermost list. Contains list of permits per zone
search_param1 json_value;
search_param2 json_value;

json_body json := my_package.parse_body(:body);
search_list2 json_list := json_ext.get_json_list(json_body,'list1');
search_list1 json_list := json_ext.get_json_list(json_body,'list2');

begin
  for i in 1..search_list1.count loop
    search_param1 := search_list1.get(i);
    for i in 1..search_list2.count loop
        search_param2 := search_list2.get(i);
        inner_json_list.append(my_package.get_permit(search_param1, search_param2).to_json_value); --do not append until check for not null return
    end loop;
    inner_json_obj.put('Inner List', inner_json_list);
    inner_json_obj.put('Inner Object Value', search_param1);
    outer_json_list.append(inner_json_obj.to_json_value()); --put if around this to check inner_json_list for null
  end loop;
  outer_json_obj.put('Outer List', outer_json_list);
  htp.p(outer_json_obj.to_char());
end;
```

Comment: And your code looks like?

Comment: edited with my existing code

Comment: It looks like `my_package.get_permit` is returning a JSON object? If so, and that is what is returning the empty object, then that would be where the culprit lies.

Comment: Yes it is. I'm aware of where the problem lies. I'm looking for how to check if that object is null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really know what you mean by `null`. All methods in the PL/JSON library return some form of JSON type. If you mean an empty object, this will work:

```
declare
  json_obj json := json('{}');
  list json_list;
begin
  list := json_obj.get_keys;

  if list.count = 0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('Empty object');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('Non-empty object');
  end if;
end;
```